# syllogism, truth-functional, or neither?

Tags: logic, syllogism

1. I dreamed that John F. Kennedy was born in 1917, and everything I dream is true. Therefore, Kennedy was born in 1917.
2. All horses are animals. Therefore, all heads of horses are heads of animals.
3. If 'There is no truth' is true, it is false. Thus, it is false.

Comment: First off welcome to philosophy.SE. For questions, you should limit yourself to one-question per question. "syllogism" is a word that has more than one functional meaning. Can you clarify the definition you were taught to use?

Comment: well to clarify, the question said "syllogistic," and for the definition, we simply learned that we can derive a conclusion from propositions and can appraise validity through venn diagrams.

Comment: What is your def of [Syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogism) ? It seems to me that you are using it as synonym of [valid argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument#Validity).

Comment: The course does not specify its definition of syllogistic sentence. I am supposing it wants me to use a general definition.

Comment: [Truth functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_function) may mean : symbolized with classical propositional logic. If so, both 1 and 2 are not truth-fucntional (they need quantifiers).

Comment: So I guessed that 1 would be syllogistic, 2 being neither, and 3 being truth functional. would that be correct?